# selector for every child of id

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net

I wish to add a css-style to every asp:label inside a fieldset with an id but can't figure out how.

I thought it would be a good idea to just select all `span` elements since that is what is created from asp:label, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is what I've got:

**jquery**

```
$("#fsLimit > span").css("border", "1px solid #3f90cb");
```

**asp**

```
<fieldset id="fsLimit">
    <legend>FieldSet</legend>
    <asp:Label id="someLabel" runat="server" text="someLabel />
</fieldset>
```

**Generated html**

```
<fieldset id="fsLimit">
    <legend>FieldSet</legend>
    <span id="GeneratedID">someLabel</span>
</fieldset>
```

**EDIT:**

Some clairification seems to be neccesary.

- I can't reproduce the problem in a fiddle. When I try it in fiddle it works fine
- "doesn't seem to work" = nothing happens. It's just an unstyled span
- I have other child elements that SHOULDN'T have the border. So I dont want ALL children.
- It's definetly a `<span>`. I've checked using Chromes "inspect element" tool.

Comment: "It doesn't seem to work" ? What do you mean ? Can you reproduce the problem in a fiddle ?

Comment: Your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/bs29x/ Have you checked the console for errors in other parts of your JS?

Comment: Why are you doing the CSS with jQuery? - Just use CSS - http://jsfiddle.net/VYnTB/

Comment: Just a note but if you are associating your label to an input then the generated html will change from a `span` to a `label`

Comment: Do you have other elements with `#fsLimit` id on the same page?

Comment: What the actual generated code? I'm pretty sure it's not whats on this question as where is `GeneratedID` coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work. As you can see in [this demo](http://jqversion.com/#!/WSSJJ3D) your code is working well.

Did you forgot to wrap your jquery code inside the document ready method?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#fsLimit > span").css("border", "1px solid #3f90cb");
});
```

Comment: No, I have it wrapped. could it be the asp that messes it up?

Comment: @JohanHjalmarsson try this `$('#fsLimit > span, #fsLimit > label')` instead of `$('#fsLimit > span')`.

Comment: Then I think you are calling the script too earlier. You have to call it after the page is loaded. I didn't worked too much with asp, but as I know it behaves like ajax, so you have to put that js function on the page change event

Comment: @MateiMihai You are righ! The problem was that I changed it before everything was loaded. Thanks!

Comment: I still don't understand why you're using jQuery do perform simple CSS?

Comment: @AlexThomas because I need to, thats why. The example is a simplified version of my code. In my code, I change the style depending on various things

Comment: "because I need to, thats why" Errrrmmm, good answer. Good luck.

Answer (score -2):

```
$("#fsLimit").children().css("border", "1px solid #3f90cb");
```

Comment: This will set the legend as well!

Comment: I have other children aswell that I dont want to apply the border to.

Comment: you said every child of id